# How to use MID function in excel to extract text with increasing start_num values?

Tags: excel

I have a long string of text in A1. I would like to extract 42 characters every 30 character length apart. How do I set this up in excel?

Example: My current formula is  =MID(A1,31,42). In the next row, I want =MID(A1,61,42), then =MID(A1,91,42) and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `ROW()` function :

`=MID(A1,ROW()*30+1,42)`